# Getting User Token for Microsoft Web N-Gram Service (Public Beta)

Tags: python, web-services, n-gram

I want to use the Python Library of the [Microsoft Web N-Gram Service (Public Beta)](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/info/) but I have to retrieve a user token from Microsoft Research in order to do so. I cannot however find how to retrieve it. It is stated at the Microsoft Web N-Gram Service info page that I have to accept the [Terms of Use](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/info/termsofuse.htm), but the link opens a plain html page that simply states the TOU.

Has someone else used the Python Library and retrieved a user token?

Comment: You didn't find [this page](http://web-ngram.research.microsoft.com/info/QuickStart.htm) where there's a link: [Request a user token from Microsoft](mailto:webngram@microsoft.com?subject=Token%20Request)?

Comment: Hello Damien, thanks for your reply. I did not check that link because I thought it was for Visual Studio usage only and did not think it would state this kind of information. Thank you this solves my issue.